# Integrate Azure Active Directory into Asp.Net Website

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.NET website ( NOT web application ) and I'm looking at how to use Azure Active Directory to authenticate users for single sign on purposes.

The samples from the File > New Project use global.asax.cs to interact with middleware, eg the WSFederationAuthenticationModule_RedirectingToIdentityProvider method. Websites dont have the global.asax or a class that inherits from HTTPApplication

Can I use Azure AD to provide single sign on capabilities for an Asp.Net Website and if so how should I go about it?